# How to create a script that takes screenshots of all pages of a given PDF file

Tags: linux, scripting, command, pdf, screenshot

I want to create a script that takes a PDF file as input and takes a screenshot of every single page in actual size(100%). So it would look like this: `custom_pdfcapture example.PDF` After execution the screenshots should lie in the same directory as `example.PDF` with their filenames following the format `${name_of_pdf}_${page_number}.pdf`. What package(s)/command(s) should I look into to do this task?

Comment: Why don't you simply separate the file into single page files?

Comment: Or if OP insist on image why not pront on virtual printer to images?

Comment: not `script that takes screenshot`, but `script that extracts`

Comment: [Google: bash split pdf into pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+split+pdf+into+pages) -> [Is there a command-line method to split a multi-page PDF file into single pages?](https://superuser.com/a/997424/1032088) -> `pdfseparate example.pdf example_%d.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

The `pdfseparate` tool of the `poppler-utils` package can extract single pages of an input pdf file.

Example:

```
pdfseparate example.pdf example_%02d.pdf
```

splits `example.pdf` into pages `example_01.pdf`, `example_02.pdf`, ... where `%02d` represents the page number in printf-style.

---

The tools `pdftocairo` and `pdftoppm` of the `poppler-utils` package can be used to create images of an input pdf file.

Examples:

```
pdftocairo -r 300 -png example.pdf

pdftocairo -scale-to-x 800 -scale-to-y -1 -png example.pdf
```

Both commands render all pages of the given document as PNG images named `example-01.png`, `example-02.png`, ...

The first command sets x and y resolution to 300 PPI (default is 150 PPI), the second sets the output width to fixed 800 pixels (`-scale-to-x 800`) and output height is determined by the aspect ratio (`-scale-to-y -1`).

You could use `-jpeg` or `-tiff` instead of `-png` to generate JPEG (see `-jpegopt` to change the JPEG compression level) or TIFF images.

If your document's MediaBox is greater than its CropBox (what Acrobat would display and print), add option `-cropbox`.

You can check the box sizes with `pdfinfo` which is also included in the package:

```
pdfinfo -box example.pdf
```

---

The `pdftoppm` utility which uses a different rendering backend needs a prefix for the output image (here `example`), the output is similar:

```
pdftoppm -r 300 -png example.pdf example
```

Please check the man pages of both commands for further options.